# How to merge array of objects if duplicate values are there, if key is common then merge common values in single key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typescript, object

This is an input array of object

```
var array= [
    { name : "c", arr: "d" },
    { name : "a", arr: "b" },
    { name : "c", arr: "e" },
    { name : "a", arr: "b" },
    { name : "c", arr: "d" }
];
```

result should be like

```
var result =[
     { name : "c", arr: "d,e" },
     { name : "a", arr: "b" }
]
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance look proper to question this differs from as you mentioned

Comment: if I have no idea how can I post my effort dude @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce`, a `Set` to store the unique letters, then `join` them together with `map` at the end:

```js
var array= [
    { name : "c", arr: "d" },
    { name : "a", arr: "b" },
    { name : "c", arr: "e" },
    { name : "a", arr: "b" },
    { name : "c", arr: "d" }
];

const res = Object.values(array.reduce((a, { name, arr }) => {
  a[name] = a[name] || { name, arr: new Set() };
  a[name].arr.add(arr);
  return a;
}, {})).map(({ name, arr }) => ({ name, arr: [...arr].join(",")}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```